# Can ping ip address of a public site but not the hostname?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

1. As the subject mentions, I can successfully ping the ip address of a public site like google, i.e. `ping 216.58.200.238` works, but `ping www.google.com` does not work and an error `name or service not known` was returned.
2. My machine is a virtual machine deployed in VMWARE workstation, 64bit CentOS7.
3. I got another exact same machine with the same setting mentioned in point 2, and I make sure they have the same network setting.  Let's call it B and previous one A.
4. `ping www.google.com` works in machine B but not machine A.
5. I also make sure that NetworkManager is diabled in both machines.
6. Below is the exact same network setting for both A and B except IP address.

   ```
   TYPE=Ethernet
   DEVICE=ens33
   NM_CONTROLLED=no
   BOOTPROTO=static
   DNS=8.8.8.8
   IPADDR=192.168.0.12(for A)/13(for B)
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
   ```

Comment: Configure a valid nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, bro! It worked! But that's strange, I have been configured two machine simultaneously and I don't understand that how come one machine got records in its nameserver but not the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your resolver configuration, the file contains information that is read by the resolver routines the first time they are invoked by a process. The file is designed to be human readable and contains a list of keywords with values that provide various types of resolver information.

Therefore if this file does not exist, only the name server on the local machine will be queried; the domain name is determined from the hostname and the domain search path is constructed from the domain name.

Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add them to the top of the file so they are used first, optionally removing or commenting out already listed servers. Currently, you may include a maximum of three nameserver lines.

**Note**: Changes made to `/etc/resolv.conf` take effect immediately.

Source: [resolve.conf](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/resolv.conf)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the name servers were already listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. I had to edit the host file (`vi /etc/hosts`) on the server I was accessing the destination server from.

Comment: Welcome , It is not constructive to repeat the accepted answer. .

Comment: @Jeff Schaller, thanks for editing my post. The above answer suggests to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` file. In my case I has to edit `/etc/hosts` and add the IP and hostname of the destination server. I cannot see this in the answer but this was the solution in my case.